# How to change properties of DrawingArea in Gtk2Hs

Tags: haskell, gtk, gtk2hs

Can someone please point me in the right direction when it comes to changing properties of an element in Gtk2Hs.

For example, how do I change the background-color of a DrawingArea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various methods for modifying a widget's style. For example to modify the background style you can use [`widgetModifyBg`](http://haskell.org/gtk2hs/docs/gtk2hs-docs-0.9.10/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Abstract-Widget.html#v%3AwidgetModifyBg) (corresponding to the C function [`gtk_widget_modify_bg()`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-modify-bg)). In principle, if you change the style for one state (e.g. StateNormal) then you should also change it for the others.

Y would suggest you describe the styles you want in an RC file, and then load that file from your application, but it seems that functions like [`gtk_rc_parse()`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/gtk-Resource-Files.html#gtk-rc-parse) are not bound in gtk2hs.

Here's an example:

```
import Graphics.UI.Gtk

main = do
    initGUI
    window <- windowNew
    window `onDestroy` mainQuit
    drawingArea <- drawingAreaNew
    window `containerAdd` drawingArea
    widgetModifyBg drawingArea StateNormal (Color 0xffff 0 0)
    widgetShowAll window
    mainGUI
```

If you need to do custom drawing based on a widget's styles, you can do that using [`widgetGetState`](http://haskell.org/gtk2hs/docs/gtk2hs-docs-0.9.10/Graphics-UI-Gtk-General-Structs.html#v%3AwidgetGetState), the `widgetStyle` property and the `styleGet*` family of functions (e.g. [`styleGetText`](http://haskell.org/gtk2hs/docs/gtk2hs-docs-0.9.10/Graphics-UI-Gtk-General-Structs.html#v%3AstyleGetText)). Here's an example of that:

```
import Graphics.Rendering.Cairo
import Graphics.UI.Gtk hiding (fill)
import Graphics.UI.Gtk.Gdk.Events (Event(Expose))

expose widget rect = do
    state <- widgetGetState widget
    style <- widget `get` widgetStyle
    (Color red green blue) <- styleGetText style state
    drawWindow <- widgetGetDrawWindow widget

    renderWithDrawable drawWindow $ do
        moveTo 50 50
        setFontSize 20
        setSourceRGB (fromIntegral red / 0xffff)
                     (fromIntegral green / 0xffff)
                     (fromIntegral blue / 0xffff)
        showText "O HAI"
        fill

    return False

main = do
    initGUI
    window <- windowNew
    window `onDestroy` mainQuit
    drawingArea <- drawingAreaNew
    drawingArea `onExpose` \(Expose sent area region count) ->
        expose drawingArea area
    window `containerAdd` drawingArea
    widgetShowAll window
    mainGUI
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the drawing area upon an event like button click? Or is the correct approach to somehow replace it with a new one?

Comment: You have to do the drawing in the expose callback (in Gtk 3, the draw callback), but you can force a redraw from an event handler using `widgetQueueDraw`.